Flex not working for my slotted children elements
I have two files under the app/ folder of my Expo app as below. Both SafeAreaView and ScrollView are stretched from top to bottom of my entire Android emulator screen. Yet, the view with green background stretch only to wrap it's own children.
Is there anything I'm missing about how <Slot /> works?
app/_layout.tsx:
return (
<SafeAreaProvider>
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Slot />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
</SafeAreaProvider>
)

app/index.tsx:
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "green"}}>
    <Text>Content</Text>
  </View>
)

